# Push Notification not working on the correct production certificate

Tags: apple-push-notifications

When i test Push Notification with `apn_development_cer`, it works with the loaded app on the **iPhone** device from **Xcode**.

But, when I am downloading the same application from App Store or with the Ad Hoc Distribution on the same iPhone device from Xcode, it just stops sending Push Notification with `apn_production_cer`.

For the sandbox instance we are using `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`, port 2195 while for the production build we are using `gateway.push.apple.com`, port 2195. We have verified that the port 2195 is not blocked by the firewall.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: actually i am also facing the same problem had you got the solution. Please let me know what i have to do to make it work with production certificate.